# Не могу найти ошибку почему функция возвращает false

Tags: php

Не могу найти ошибку из за которой функция `getPost` возращает false

`getPosts` работает

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkXcE.jpg

В базе всего 2 поста.

index.php

```
<?php

header('Content-type: json/application');

require_once 'config/connect.php';
require_once 'functions.php';

$q = $_GET['q'];

$params = explode("/", $q);
$type = $params[0];
$id = $params[1];

if($type === 'posts'){
    if(isset($id)){
        getPost($dbh, $id);
    }else{
        getPosts($dbh);
    }
}
```

functions.php

```
<?php


function getPosts($dbh){
    $stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM `posts`");
    $post = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($post);
}

function getPost($dbh, $id){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = ?";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute([$id]);
    if(!$stmt){
        echo 'error';
    }else{
        $post = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($post);
    }
}
```

.htaccess

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

connect.php

```
<?php

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=api_tester', 'root', 'root');
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage();
    die();
  }
```

Comment: И `getPosts`, и `getPost`, по сути ,ничего не возвращают, там нет `return`. Или вы имеете ввиду то, что они в `echo` выводят?

Comment: да в консоле , в postman

Comment: А что будет в `getPost` в `echo $post`? Какие значения ожидаются получить, а какие приходят из базы?

Comment: 1  пост. id поста , title поста, body поста

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/wqkwX11

Answer (score 1):

`var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());` 
Ошибка была в том, что в базе не было поля id, вместо него был post_id